# Mathplotlib graph problems

Tags: python, graph

I'm trying to display data from a weather station with mathplotlib. For some reason that I can't quite figure out my last values on the graph are acting randomly, going back in time on the x axis.

x axis is the dates,

y axis is the water level

y1 axis is the discharge flow

Here's a picture of the result
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32V0m.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url_hourly = "https://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv/BC/hourly/BC_08MG005_hourly_hydrometric.csv"
url_daily  = "https://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv/BC/daily/BC_08MG005_daily_hydrometric.csv"
fields = ["Date","Water Level / Niveau d'eau (m)", "Discharge / Débit (cms)"]

#Read csv files  
hourly_data = pd.read_csv(url_hourly, usecols=fields)
day_data = pd.read_csv(url_daily, usecols=fields)

#Merge csv files
water_data = pd.concat([day_data,hourly_data])

#Convert date to datetime
water_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(water_data['Date']).dt.normalize()
water_data['Date'] = water_data['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

# CSV files contains 288 data entries per day (12per hour * 24hrs). Selecting every 288th element to represent one day
data_24hr = water_data[::288]

# Assigning columns to x, y, y1 axis
x = data_24hr[fields[0]]
y1 = data_24hr[fields[1]]
y2= data_24hr[fields[2]]

#Ploting the graph
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
curve1 = ax1.plot(x,y1, label='Water Level', color = 'r', marker="o")
curve2 = ax2.plot(x,y2,label='Discharge Volume', color = 'b',marker="o")
plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated as I'm quite new to this

thank you

Comment: Why is one dataset called `daily` and the other `hourly`, when they are both sampled every five minutes?

Comment: Anyway, you need to remove duplicates resulting from overlap between the two datasets, and maybe sort by time and make sure that there really are 288 entries for each day. Then the plot should turn out as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Not sure why the weather station named their datasets like that... makes it confusing. I found the duplicate data don't know how I missed it the first time. I'll try and figure out how to delete them. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Okay I went through the code removed the duplicates (as suggest by Arne) by the "Date" column. Oh and I made the graph formatting slightly more readable. This graphed without going back in time:

```css
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker

url_hourly = "https://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv/BC/hourly/BC_08MG005_hourly_hydrometric.csv"
url_daily  = "https://dd.weather.gc.ca/hydrometric/csv/BC/daily/BC_08MG005_daily_hydrometric.csv"
fields = ["Date","Water Level / Niveau d'eau (m)", "Discharge / Débit (cms)"]

#Read csv files  
hourly_data = pd.read_csv(url_hourly, usecols=fields)
day_data = pd.read_csv(url_daily, usecols=fields)

#Merge csv files
water_data = pd.concat([day_data,hourly_data])

#Convert date to datetime
water_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(water_data['Date']).dt.normalize()
water_data['Date'] = water_data['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
# CSV files contains 288 data entries per day (12per hour * 24hrs). Selecting every 288th element to represent one day
data_24hr = water_data.iloc[::288]
data_24hr.drop_duplicates(subset="Date",inplace=True) #remove duplicates according to the date column
# Assigning columns to x, y, y1 axis
x = data_24hr[fields[0]]
y1 = data_24hr[fields[1]]
y2= data_24hr[fields[2]]

print(len(x), len(y1))
#Ploting the graph
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = plt.twinx()
curve1 = ax1.plot(x, y1, label='Water Level', color = 'r', marker="o")
curve2 = ax2.plot(x, y2, label='Discharge Volume', color = 'b',marker="o")
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks!  Was about to try to figure out how to rotate those dates, easier than I thought.